# ffmpeg extracting frames from video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using [Writingminds FFmpeg](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) to use FFmpeg with Android. I am currently trying to extract frames from a video.

I would like to extract 8 frames from the video evenly distributed throughout the video. I found this [tutorial](http://muzso.hu/2008/12/28/extracting-thumbnails-still-images-frames-from-a-video-with-ffmpeg) here is my implementation of it.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    Long videoLength = Long.parseLong(time);


final String cmd[] = {

            "-i",
            videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-f",
            "image2",
            "-ss",
            String.valueOf(videoLength.intValue() / ((8 + 1) * 10)),
            "-r",
            String.valueOf((8 + 1) / videoLength.intValue()),
            mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/%d.jpg"
    };
```

However, when i go to the folder where the frames should be saved there isn't anything there. Also there are no error messages.

I feel like its a way this library takes the String parameters. I've been stuck on this for sometime I have tried lots of different versions of the `cmd`. I was hoping someone could help.

Here is my output from ffmpeg:

```
1-22 19:33:14.904 30981-30981/com.firebase.android D/videoFrames:  failure reason ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
         built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
         configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
         libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
         libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
         libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
         libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
         libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
         libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
         libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
         libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.firebase.android/cache/videovgntp6q5ar4dglkaflaoobfpcv945824159.mp4':
         Metadata:
           major_brand     : isom
           minor_version   : 512
           compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
           encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
         Duration: 00:00:08.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 391 kb/s
           Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x764 [SAR 1:1 DAR 180:191], 132 kb/s, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 12800 tbn, 33.33 tbc (default)
           Metadata:
             handler_name    : VideoHandler
           Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
           Metadata:
             handler_name    : SoundHandler
       Invalid framerate value: 0
```

**Update 2**

Here is my Android code:

```
      try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d("videoFrames", "starting to load binary");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                Log.d("videoFrames", "failed to load binary");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("videoFrames", "loaded binary");
                try {
                    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStart() {
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " starting to get frames from video");
                            if (mediaStorageDir.isDirectory() && mediaStorageDir.list().length > 0) {
                                String[] children = mediaStorageDir.list();
                                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                                    new File(mediaStorageDir, children[i]).delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(String message) {
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " progress getting frames from video");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(String message) {
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " failed to get frames from video");
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " failure reason " + message);
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " ----------------------------------------------- ");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String message) {
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " success getting frames from video");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            Log.d("videoFrames", " finished getting frames from video");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                    Log.d("videoFrames", " command already running in fmpeg");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }
```

**Update 3**

I fixed my code by doing:

```
 final String cmd[] = {

            "-i",
            videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-f",
            "image2",
            "-ss",
            String.valueOf(videoLength.floatValue() / (8.0  * 10.0)),
            "-r",
            String.valueOf(8.0 / videoLength.floatValue()),
            mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/%d.jpg"
    };
```

Comment: Show the ffmpeg command that the code executes and also show the complete log from ffmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Updated question sorry it didnt format well

Comment: I updated my question with the android code. Yes that is the complete log. If you look at onFailure(..) I write the failure message is... and thats what I posted here. Also the input file is just a video I recorded on my phone that is definitely not the problem. Because other commands work if for example I just get all frames from a video and dont use -r

Comment: Also the ffmpeg command is what I showed you. The variable `cmd`

Comment: This is literally everything related to the execution I am printing everything I can https://pastebin.com/ix1MKu8G

Comment: I guess there is no way to get the actual ffmpeg command then? You can't echo the result of the `cmd` variable? If not, all I can do is guess is that you are using `-r 0` which is not valid.

Comment: Ah I think I know whats happening. I did `(8 + 1) / 14` where my video had a length of 14 and i get the answer 0.64 on my calculator. Is it possible the double isnt storing the number properly because its small?

Comment: Thank you @LordNeckbeard You helped me fix the problem. But I dont always get a fixed number of frames that tutorial said you get a fixed number of frames. Mine ranges from 8-11 depending on length of video. Also how can I get the time at which the frame was captured? Thanks

Comment: That's a new question. I recommend you post your solution as the answer regarding the `Invalid framerate value` and ask a new question about the frame interval, and because it is a ffmpeg question and not related to your code you can show your unscripted, actual ffmpeg command and exclude the additional complexity of the code.